# Proving Convergence using the definition of limits

Tags: real-analysis

I must prove convergence for the following:

A sequence defined as: $\large\frac{(1+4n)^2}{1-3n-6n^2}$

Using the $\epsilon - n_{0}$ definition.

I'm running into trouble when I try to define $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$. I think I have it boiled down to  $\large\frac{5}{-18n^2-9n+3} \leq \epsilon$

However, I cant seem to figure out how to find $n$ > (whatever) $\epsilon$

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, do you know what this sequence converges to?

Comment: -8/3 I believe. I was going the the $|x_{n} - a| < \epsilon$ procedure

Comment: @PaulGerard: Believe something else.

Comment: my apologies....editing the question now

Comment: still not $-8/3$... :)

Comment: ahhh is it not 16/-6 = -8/3??

Comment: Now the limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: sorry again about the error in the question

Comment: im really bad at posting questions, sorry

Comment: Hint: Sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $-\infty$ if for every $L\in\mathbb{R}$, exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$, s.t for all $n\geq n_0$, $a_n<L$.

Comment: You changed it again!

Comment: You finally got it right. Now, indeed, the limit is $-8/3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gasp! You've changed the question again!

We know that the limit is $-\frac{16}{6}$.
This can be seen for instance by factoring out $n^2$ in the numerator and in the denominator.

Then 
$$
\frac{(1+4n)^2}{1-3n-6n^2}+\frac{16}{6}=\frac{13}{3(1-3n-6n^2)}.
$$

So for all $n\geq 1$,
$$
0\leq -\left(\frac{1+4n^2}{1-3n-6n^2}+\frac{16}{6}\right) \leq \frac{13}{18n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}.
$$

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and now take $n_0$ large enough such that $n_0>1/\epsilon$.

Then for all $n\geq n_0$, you have
$$
\lvert \frac{1+4n^2}{1-3n-6n^2}+\frac{16}{6} \rvert \leq \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n_0}<\epsilon.
$$

So the limit is indeed $-16/6=-8/3$.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Due to the question change the answer is the following:

By the limit laws we see that the limit is $L==-\frac83$. So we want
$$\left|a_n-L\right|=\left|\frac{(1+4n)^2}{1-3n-6n^2}+\frac83\right|=\frac13\left|\frac{11}{1-3n-6n^2}\right|\le \epsilon\iff \left|\frac{1}{1-3n-6n^2}\right|\le \frac{3\epsilon}{11}$$
when $n\ge N$. But for $n\ge 2$,
$$\left|\frac{1}{1-3n-6n^2}\right|=\frac{1}{6n^2+3n-1}\le\frac{1}{6n^2}$$
We therefore want
$$\frac6{n^2}\le\frac{3\epsilon}{11} \iff n^2\ge \frac{66}{3\epsilon}\iff  n\ge \sqrt{\frac{66}{3\epsilon}}$$
Picking $N=\max\left\{k,2\right\}$ where $k\ge \sqrt{\frac{66}{3\epsilon}}$ will do